# Nautilus not opening when using "Attach a photo or video" option of Facebook

Tags: firefox, nautilus, facebook

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

A few days ago, I left my computer on for a couple of days straight. Since then I cannot upload pictures to facebook using the "attach a photo or video" icon.

Typically, in Facebook, if I want to attach a photo to a comment, I click on the camera icon which summons the file manager, Nautilus. But Nautilus isn't appearing. In other words, when I click on the camera icon, nothing happens.

I can use the photo feature using my Android phone or Tablet but not using either Firefox or Chromium on Ubuntu.

I have tried uninstalling Firefox and then reinstalling but the problem remains.

Comment: Do you have any network shares in your *file-system table*, as those shares may have become disconnected during the *couple of days straight* you were using it, and if you re-connect to those shares, you'll find normal behavior returns.  You gave no specifics as to what directories you're trying to use thus we can really only guess.

Comment: Did you try rebooting the computer?

Comment: I have rebooted several times and as far as I know, there are no network shares

Comment: I have tried this in Opera, Firefox and Chromium. The same behavior in each. However, drop and drag works. I have added Facebook as an exception to the pop-up blocker and I've tried switching off the pop-up blocker. I've tried re-installing Nautilus. Nothing changes. I've no idea even where to look now.